# Getting TypeScript Error in MUI palette customization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to add a custom colour in MUI v5 with TypeScript but It gives me

> Type '"my_custom_color"' is not assignable to type '"primary" | "inherit" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning" | undefined'.

I have followed all the steps mentioned in MUI documentation

```ts
import {createTheme} from "@mui/material";

export default createTheme({
    palette: {
        my_custom_color: {
            main: "#e82020"
        }
    }
});

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
    interface Palette {
        my_custom_color: Palette["primary"];
    }

    interface PaletteOptions {
        my_custom_color: PaletteOptions["primary"];
    }

   
    }
}
```

But it still throws a type error

```ts
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <Button variant={"contained"} color={"my_custom_color"}></Button>
   </ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding a custom color to your theme you provide a `string`

```js
export default createTheme({
  palette: {
    my_custom_color: {
      main: "#e82020",
    },
  },
});
```

When trying to type your theme you provide `Palette['primary]` as a type. But this is not valid since `primary` is a object, [see palette customization](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#customization). Instead what you can do a type your `my_custom_color` as a string.

```js
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Palette {
    my_custom_color: string;
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    my_custom_color: string;
  }
}
```